# pandas: rebase data to begin with first value over a certain size?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
d = [
    { "name": "Bob", "1/1/20": 10, "1/2/20": 24, "1/3/20": 38 },
    { "name": "Charlie", "1/1/20": 0, "1/2/20": 0, "1/3/20": 5 },
    { "name": "Helen", "1/1/20": 4, "1/2/20": 14, "1/3/20": 24 },
    { "name": "Sarah", "1/1/20": 2, "1/2/20": 4, "1/3/20": 11 }
]
```

I'd like to rebase this data so for each person, it begins at the first day where the value is above 10.

I also want to rename the columns so that they are relative to the first day with a value above 10, not absolute days.

In other words, I'd like an output dataframe that looks like this:

```
name     day1     day2     day2
Bob      10       24       38
Charlie  
Helen    14       24
Sarah    11
```

Is this possible in pandas?

UPDATE: Perhaps I should break this down into smaller tasks:

- row-wise, extract an array of all values above 100
- for each row, append this to a new array of arrays, and right-pad with null values.

Possibly it would be better not to use pandas at all?

Comment: What does `day1`, `day2` etc mean in this case, can you make it consistent with your example dataset provided. Also, if you want values `> 10`, why is `5` not removed?

Comment: Apologies - updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.set_index('name', inplace=True)
df.where(df >= 10).stack().to_frame('Value'). \
    assign(Day=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1). \
    reset_index(level=0).pivot('name', 'Day', 'Value').add_prefix('Day').reindex(df.index)
Out[37]: 
Day      Day1  Day2  Day3
name                     
Bob      10.0  24.0  38.0
Charlie   NaN   NaN   NaN
Helen    14.0  24.0   NaN
Sarah    11.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Might want a `.reindex(df.index)` there to bring "Charlie" back...

Comment: I think it is faster here to use numpy

Comment: @ansev you assumed the value is increasing for each day